# SharedPreferences not working onResume

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Got a problem with the Shared Preferences in Android - I want to be able to put some Strings (Save the IDs of a Picture) as favorite for the next launches - it works perfect, it recognizes if the ID is already inside the Shared Preferences and removes it if necessary, but when I stop the App by pressing the home button (without killing the app process) and then return to it, it doesn´t recognize it anymore. If I kill the process and restart the app, it works fine.

So here´s my code

**MainActivity onCreate**

```
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

**MainActivity onResume**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    super.onResume();
}
```

I´ve already tried to do it without onResume but it doesn´t change the result.

**Method to change the Shared Preferences**

```
if (checkTheSharedPreferences(numberFavo)){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favo);
        edit.putString(pref, pref);
        edit.apply();
        showIt = "Zu Favoriten hinzugefügt";


    }else{
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favo2);
        edit.remove(pref);
        edit.apply();
        showIt = "Aus Favoriten entfernt";

    }
```

If my method to check if the SharedPreferences returns true it means that the String isn´t inside the SharedPrefs and can be added, otherwise it will be removed as the user wants to remove it from his favorites.

**Method to check if the String is inside the Prefs**

```
public Boolean checkTheSharedPreferences(int number) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> map = preferences.getAll();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().toString().equals(bilderIDs.get(number))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As mentioned above, it works perfect, unless the App gets invisible/into the background and is opened again without a restart.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Seems like it works if I wait for about 30 seconds after onResume is called, but that´s not really a possibility to wait for so long as it is on the UI Thread and the User might presses the button to remove/add the SharedPref within the 30 seconds

Comment: did you debug that onResume method is called or not ??

Comment: Just put code after super.onResume.

Comment: Not working, sorry, and onResumed is called @VivekMishra

Comment: So,change apply to commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharedPreferences.Editor.apply() is a async method.It will store values in other thread.SharedPreferences.Editor.commit() is a sync method.

```
if (checkTheSharedPreferences(numberFavo)){
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favo);
    edit.putBoolean("myfav" + numberFavo, true);
    edit.commit();
    showIt = "Zu Favoriten hinzugefügt";
}else{
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favo2);
    edit.remove("myfav" + numberFavo);
    edit.commit();
    showIt = "Aus Favoriten entfernt";
}
public Boolean checkTheSharedPreferences(int number) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean("myfav" + number,false);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = getSharedPreferences("favo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
}
```

Comment: Where do you put your Method to change the Shared Preferences?

Comment: The method is inside the MainActivity (as every other method I´m calling during this process). The method to change the Shared Preferences is called when the User presses a custom button.

Comment: I edit some code for your to make it clear to understand.Can you replace your code?

Comment: I can´t use a boolean to store because the String I´m storing represents the ID of a picture I need to access the correct URL from a webserver.

Comment: The key still cantains the ID.when you need it , you can get it.